# The server principal is not able to access the database under the current security context. - connecting string

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am using classic asp and trying to access to a remote sql server.
Even though I am specifing which database is default, connection is trying to access another database and yes, user does not have access to it.
I double check user properties where the default database is correctly set and mapped. Here is my connecting string..

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=1.1.1.1\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=DEFAULTDB;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX
```

Comment: Can you use those details to login to SSMS or through another tool. Can you then return the data you would expect to?

Comment: Yes Mike, I can retrieve data from the database it is mapped to, I checked it with SSMS

Comment: @masirov With the same Username and Password defined in the connection string?

Comment: Of course, authentication information is correct. But when I use SA there is no problem. But we do not want to use it because its unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We sorted it out. DBA told me that while using X database, the trigger is using another database too. So we had to authorize for that database and problem was solved.

Thank you for your contribution.